# Is it OK to reduce fan speed by reducing voltage?

Tags: voltage, motor, fan, rpm, ac-motor

I have this air cooler whose speed is just too much even on the lowest speed setting, so I added one more speed controller(or regulator) in series  which is basically used to control the ceiling fan speed. It works fine but its also making some unusual noise.

My only concern is that if it can burn the motor or something.

Here is the circuit diagram of the fan
The speed regulator which I installed is marked with red.

[image: The speed regulator which I installed is marked with red]

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the speed controller details? Typically there are two types of speed controllers available in the market - capacitor based ones and triac based ones. Earlier (20 years back) there used to be resistive speed controllers as well but I don't see them being used these days.

Capacitor based speed controllers add a series capacitor in the circuit. There is some voltage drop across the capacitor and fan motor gets a lesser voltage across it. This results in RPM reduction. These speed controllers typically wont make a hum sound in the fan motor. I don't see a harm in using two of these in series to reduce the speed even further.

Triac based speed controllers use a phase control method to transmit lower overall voltage to the motor (search triac phase control to learn more about this). In this case, there is a sharp voltage edge being fed to the motor at twice the line frequency. This results in a humming sound in the motor. In most of the cases, even this one in series with a capacitor based speed control should be fine provided it is getting the right working voltage. However two of these in series might act weird in some cases.

My guess is - your second speed controller is triac based. It would be better if you can replace it with a capacitor based speed controller. However I dont have the complete info to conclude whether the current setup with destroy the motor or not.

Answer (score 1):

[image: AC reducer]

I have used this kind of circuit to lower the voltage to a fan using a small transformer. The secondary voltage is the amount you want to reduce the voltage by, and it should be rated to carry the current. (If you wire the secondary the wrong way, it will increase the voltage.)

Answer (score -1):

Caution, the transformer circuit works, much better then a resistor but will also boost the voltage if either the primary or secondary leads are reversed. If you drop it to much the motor slip will increase to much and cause the motor to heat. low voltage is a major cause of motor overheating and premature failure. The low voltage causes the motor to draw more current to deliver the power expected of it thus overheating the motor windings. Also as a fan motor slows down it requires less energy as it is doing less work. This generally works with smaller motors such as yours.  Your best solution is a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive).

That motor has three speeds, are sure you are controlling the low speed? The low speed will have more poles and be closer to its rating then the other two speeds.